# Grep pattern Matching Doesn't work?

Tags: grep

I have a text file like so:

```
"Id","District Name","Neighborhood Name","Street","Weekday","Month","Day","Hour","Part of the day","Mild injuries","Serious injuries","Victims","Vehicles involved","Longitude","Latitude"
"2017S008429    ","Unknown","Unknown","Número 27                                         ","Friday","October",13,8,"Morning",2,0,2,2,2.12562442,41.34004482
"2017S007316    ","Unknown","Unknown","Número 3 Zona Franca / Número 50 Zona Franca      ","Friday","September",1,13,"Morning",2,0,2,2,2.12045245,41.33942606
"2017S010210    ","Unknown","Unknown","Litoral (Besòs)                                   ","Friday","December",8,21,"Afternoon",5,0,5,2,2.1673561,41.3608855
"2017S006364    ","Unknown","Unknown","Número 3 Zona Franca                              ","Friday","July",21,2,"Night",1,0,1,2,2.12452894,41.33766786
"2017S004615    ","Sant Martí","el Camp de l'Arpa del Clot","Las Navas de Tolosa                               ","Thursday","May",25,14,"Afternoon",1,0,1,3,2.185272,41.416365
"2017S007775    ","Sant Martí","el Camp de l'Arpa del Clot","Indústria / Trinxant                              ","Wednesday","September",20,12,"Morning",1,0,1,2,2.183245,41.416336
"2017S004484    ","Sant Martí","el Camp de l'Arpa del Clot","Trinxant / Indústria                              ","Saturday","May",20,21,"Afternoon",1,0,1,2,2.183245,41.416336
"2017S010680    ","Sant Martí","el Camp de l'Arpa del Clot","Indústria                                         ","Tuesday","December",26,20,"Afternoon",2,0,2,1,2.183561,41.416372
"2017S005152    ","Sant Martí","el Camp de l'Arpa del Clot","Indústria                                         ","Monday","June",12,15,"Afternoon",1,0,1,1,2.184059,41.416763
"2017S003932    ","Sant Martí","el Camp de l'Arpa del Clot","Maragall                                          ","Wednesday","May",3,20,"Afternoon",1,0,1,1,2.181225,41.413958
"2017S010348    ","Sant Martí","el Camp de l'Arpa del Clot","Indústria                                         ","Thursday","December",14,20,"Afternoon",1,0,1,2,2.18229,41.415772
"2017S000245    ","Sant Martí","el Camp de l'Arpa del Clot","ST ANTONI M CLARET / Pg Maragall                  ","Wednesday","January",11,7,"Morning",1,0,1,2,2.180453,41.41579
"2017S005695    ","Sant Martí","el Camp de l'Arpa del Clot","Sant Antoni Maria Claret / Guinardó               ","Friday","June",30,12,"Morning",1,0,1,2,2.18114,41.416295
"2017S007384    ","Sant Martí","el Camp de l'Arpa del Clot","Sant Antoni Maria Claret                          ","Monday","September",4,16,"Afternoon",0,1,1,2,2.176324,41.412546
"2017S008080    ","Sant Martí","el Camp de l'Arpa del Clot","Sant Antoni Maria Claret                          ","Saturday","September",30,19,"Afternoon",1,0,1,2,2.176324,41.412546
"2017S003439    ","Sant Martí","el Camp de l'Arpa del Clot","Còrsega / Còrsega                                 ","Monday","April",17,14,"Afternoon",1,0,1,2,2.178314,41.410784
"2017S002410    ","Sant Martí","el Camp de l'Arpa del Clot","CÒRSEGA / Dos de Maig                             ","Saturday","March",25,14,"Afternoon",4,0,4,2,2.177719,41.410323
"2017S009296    ","Sant Martí","el Camp de l'Arpa del Clot","Indústria                                         ","Thursday","November",9,22,"Night",1,0,1,1,2.17674,41.411445
```

I tried something like:

```
grep "May ,25" $1
```

where `$1` is the filename which the user inputs in. So basically it is supposed to find the rows that contain the date May, 25, but it displays absolutely nothing. I know for a fact that there are rows that contain the date May, 25.

I also tried the following, but it still does not work:

```
grep "\"May\" ,25" $1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quotes are characters too - your files doesn't contain `May,25`, it contains `"May",25`. So

```
grep '"May",25' "$1"
```

or

```
grep "\"May\",25" "$1"
```

(but **not** `grep "\"May\" ,25" "$1"` - spaces are characters as well).

Or you can use a CSV aware tool that understands CSV quoting:

```
mlr --csv filter 'Month == "May" && Day == 25'

csvgrep -c Month -m May "$1" | csvgrep -c Day -m 25
```

Comment: Just wondering I got a file like file1.txt that has all the dates formatted like this one, So like it has the "May",25 and I wanted to find the dates in this file that matches the one on the other one, so I tried ```cat file1.txt | xargs -I{} grep -E {} "$1"``` but that obviously doesnt work because the quotes need to be escaped is there a simple fix for this??

Comment: @YunfeiChen `grep` already has the ability to read a list of patterns from a file (they need to be one per line though) - `grep -f file1.txt "$1"` (or `grep -F -f file1.txt "$1"` since the dates are simple fixed strings rather than regular expressions).